# How do I use a variable (number value) into another value (like pixel value) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to use a JavaScript variable as an HTML pixel value, but I don't know how to use it in a string.

Here's the code:

```js
a = 20;
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
h1.style.fontSize = '{a}px';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which add in a string to the second string.

Here's an example:

```js
const a = 50;
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
h1.style.fontSize = `${a}px`;
```

```html
<h1> Hello </h1>
```

Or, you can use concatenation for bringing strings together:

```js
a + "px";
// "50px"
```

Be careful when using concatenation, because if you use a number (like 50) it will add up the string plus the number. You can use `a.toString()` or `String(a)` to convert it to a string.

```js
50 + "px"; // "50px"

"50" + "px"; // "50px"

(50).toString() + "px"; // "50px"

String(50) + "px"; // "50px"
```